# SQL - Joining Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

The following query used to grab all comments for a particular blog article and worked well. I've now added a members reputation point system to my blog, similar to Stack Overflow's reputation system, and tried modifying this query to get the reputation points from the members_reputation table, to display next to the user's name on each comment.

I thought by adding SUM(rep.points) AS member_rep and adding a LEFT JOIN on the reputation table would do the trick but I'm getting strange results, too strange to describe. Actually, one funny behaviour is that not all the comments are being returned. Where if I removed my attempted solution, all comments are returned but I need to count/show their reputation.

Every comment has a member and every member has reputation.

```
SELECT comment.comment_id, comment.member_id, comment.comment,
comment.posted, member.screen_name, member.country_code, SUM(rep.points) AS member_rep
FROM blog_comments AS comment
LEFT JOIN members AS member ON comment.member_id = member.member_id

// my attempt start //
LEFT JOIN members_reputation AS rep ON comment.member_id = rep.member_id
// my attempt end //

WHERE comment.article_id = "&article_id&"
ORDER BY comment.comment_id DESC
```

**DB Structure**

```
comments              :    comment_id, member_id, comment, posted
members               :    member_id, screen_name, country_code
members_reputation    :    member_id, activity_type, points
```

**What I want to see**

```
This is a posted comment on my blog. Cool huh?
25/02/2012 By Martin G **850** (GBR)
```

If anyone can help me get back on the right road, I would be very grateful...

Comment: Instead of joining directly to the new table, join to a subquery of the new table, e.g., `FROM (SELECT member_id, COUNT(*) FROM members_reputation GROUP BY member_id) AS SubQuery`.

Comment: If you look at the 'strange' result eg where one is missing, have you followed the joins through to prove it would find a populated reputation ? Is points nullable?

Comment: Mmmm, and this was down-voted for...? It's on-topic, good enough written description, provided code, not a duplicate as it's application specific, and I made an attempt. How am I supposed to improve my questions when you down-vote and run off? Grrr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a couple of things I noticed.

First, your where clause is asking for comment.article_id, which you haven't included in your table structure at the bottom of your post. I'm going to make the assumption that you just left it out, but thought I'd point it out anyways.

You can also simplify your joins by specifying USING instead of ON if the column name is the same in both tables.

Another thing to consider is the type of relationship you have between the tables. If it's a one to one relationship than joins are simple. If it's a one to many or many to many than joins get more complicated and you have to GROUP them together properly. I'm going to assume that each comment has only one member, and every member may have more than one rep.

Finally, you have a column that shares a name with a table alias (comment). This can lead to problems, if your sql syntax even allows it.

This is what I'd use, myself:

```
SELECT c.comment_id, c.member_id, c.comment, c.posted, m.screen_name, m.country_code
       SUM(r.points) `member_rep`
FROM blog_comments `c`
LEFT JOIN members `m` USING (member_id)
LEFT JOIN members_reputation `r` USING (member_id)
WHERE c.article_id = "&article_id&"
ORDER BY c.comment_id DESC
```

Also: what does the "&article_id&" represent?

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. "&article_id&" is a classic ASP variable that represents the current blog article. Yes, I did accidentally leave out comment.article_id from the DB structure. You are also right where each comment has one member, and each member has more than one rep, hence using the SUM function to count all rep points for that member

Comment: Although the query is a lot easier to read, it still produces weird results.

Comment: If the statement above didn't work, let me know what kind of results you're getting and we can try to work out a better solution.

Comment: I don't think I can join the reputation table, as the select query is returning 2 comments for that article, so when I want to add the reputation, it's adding all reputation points for all the comments, not per member. Lets say member1 has 10 points and member2 has 20 points and they both wrote a comment. When I go and print the results, it will only display one comment like: [Member1 Rep:30] showing the total reputation for all comments together.

Comment: Ok, lets assume that your rep table has many rows for each member, all with a different point score. What you're going to need to do is group your query so that each member is treated as a single row, rather than as multiple rows. An easy way to test this is to simply go into your mysql client and run the query minus the SUM and see how many rows get returned, then try grouping it by c.member_id and see how many get returned (should be less). Finally, add the sum back in and see what the result is. It's good practice anyways!

Comment: Well, I think I have it. I added a GROUP BY to c.member_id using the SUM as well, like you suggested, and the rep points count for each member was spot on. This was fine until a member wrote two comments on the same article; as I submitted the comment, I could see the rep points on the last comment of mine had increased, but the new comment wasn't displayed. So I changed the GROUP BY to c.comment_id, c.member_id and I appear to have all the correct comments and points. You've been a great help and I'm very appreciative :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Joins are a pain, especially when you're first learning them.